# A specific word for the way leaves/petals carpet the ground?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm wondering if there's a specific word for the way leaves or petals carpet and scatter on the ground. I can think of all sorts of beautiful poetic ways to describe the way it sprinkles like confetti, but is there an unusual or old word for it? I like to think there is a word for it in German or Japanese.

edit: eg "The crimson petals from the cherry tree scattered the lawn."

Comment: Is there anything wrong with "carpet" or it's softer cousin "blanket"?

Comment: The OP did ask for "an unusual or old word". I can see why neither "carpet" nor "blanket" fits his/her quest.

Comment: 'Scattered the lawn' would be what an out-of-control snow-plough might have done.

Comment: In that particular sentence I expect ***littered** the ground*.

Answer (score 2):

The verb **sprinkle** has a stative transitive usage as well as the more common dynamic transitive usage, though I can only find endorsement from internet examples:

- *Colored leaves sprinkled the ground and hung from the branches of the trees.* [[The Art of Autumn Awareness | F.W. Rick Meyers; Google](The Art of Autumn Awareness | F.W. Rick Meyers)]
- *Dead leaves sprinkled the ground, too numerous to count.* [[Recovery ... DeviantArt; Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22leaves+sprinkled+the%22&ei=KVi6YPuVEYmbgAaY0LWoDw&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi7zu-dtv7wAhWJDcAKHRhoDfUQ8tMDegQIARA2&biw=1511&bih=841)]
- *At one point there was a canopy of red trees overhead while fallen red leaves sprinkled the ground.* [[The Adventures of a Newly Crippled. Elisabeth McKnight;Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22leaves+sprinkled+the%22&ei=M1m6YP35J9iT8gLst4PABQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi93_Gct_7wAhXYiVwKHezbAFg4ChDy0wN6BAgBEDg&biw=1511&bih=841)]
- *A few fallen leaves sprinkled the dewed grass.* [[FanFiction; Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22leaves+sprinkled+the%22&ei=xlm6YJ7wHo6NhbIP9KqouA8&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwie6_Tit_7wAhWORkEAHXQVCvc4FBDw0wN6BAgBEEQ&biw=1511&bih=841)]

Answer (score 2):

If you seek a word different from your own *sprinkle*, you might say “The ground was bedecked with petals.”

> Bedeck = to decorate or cover:
>
> “The room was bedecked with flowers.”
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bedeck)

The word is closely associated with German *bedeckt* = *covered*. According to Google ngram it was in good use as early as 1800, reached a small peak in the mid 1800s, declined since but is still in occasional use today.

Comment: This is wonderful, I'm going to try and bring it back into the mainstream! Thank you!